# What's the difference between PlaceboTransaction and TopLevelTransaction

Tags: neo4j

```
Transaction beginTx = db.beginTx();
try {
 // do update neo4j
  beginTx.success();
  System.println("ok");
} catch (Exception ex) {
} finally {
 beginTx.close();
}
```

Console prints "ok". But my data is not saved to neo4j and I found this transaction is PlaceboTransaction.

Answer (score 3):

> Transactions in Neo4j does not support nesting. They are flat.

So, Database states that transaction nesting isn’t supported. However, as developer we **can** create another transaction inside transaction.

```
try (Transaction parentTx = db.beginTx()) {
    try (Transaction childTx = db.beginTx()) {
    }
}
```

There is when `TopLevelTransaction` and `PlaceboTransaction` comes into play.

When another transaction is started in same thread, instead of creating new `TopLevelTransaction`, database wraps existing transaction into `PlaceboTransaction`.

`PlaceboTransaction` delegates all methods to underlying transactions. So, when you call `success()` or `failure()` it is delegated to root `TopLevelTransaction`.

One exception to this rule is `close()` method. When you close `PlaceboTransaction` it actually does nothing. In this way you can safely `close()` all “child” transaction and parent transaction will be still active.

---

Notes:

- Use `try-with-resource` syntax. It is available in Java7. Using this syntax is safe way to work with Neo4j transactions and esnure that they are closed.
- Always close previous transactions.
- Transactions in Neo4j are thread-bound. You can’t start several transactions in same thread.

Answer (score 1):

According to [rubyforge](http://neo4j.rubyforge.org/Neo4j/PlaceboTransaction.html), a PlaceboTransaction is created when you are creating a transaction while another one already exists. Also:

> This class will do nothing when the finish method is called. Finish
>   will only be called when the ‘real’ transaction does it.

So, you are getting a PlaceboTransaction because you create a Transaction while you already have one running. A placeboTransaction does nothing to database, it is commited for real when the "already running" Transaction is finished.